# How the solve the parameter of the conjugate permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutation, group-theory

As we know the definition of conjugate permutations is:
 $$\exists p \quad p^{-1} \alpha p=\beta$$
When I have an `alpha=Cycles[{{1,4},{2,5,6,3}}]` and a `beta=Cycles[{{1,2,5,3},{4,6}}]`.
So how to use `Mathematica` to solve the $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theoretical work from [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/778365/332197).

---

Happy to show my own `finP`.And I'm glad to seen another better solution can do this all the same. :)

```
findP[Cycles[c1_], Cycles[c2_]] := Module[{l},
    l = Map[Sort, {c1, c2}];
    Map[PermutationCycles,
        Map[Last,
            Map[Function @ Union[Transpose @ Map[Catenate, l], #],
                Function[list,
                    Map[Function @ Transpose @ {First @ list, #},
                        Permutations @ Last @ list
                    ]
                ][
                    Map[Function @ Complement[Range @ Max @ l, Flatten @ #], l]
                ]
            ],
            {2}
        ]
    ]
]
```

#Usage:
$\color{blue}{\text{First example}}$

```
findP[Cycles[{{1, 4}, {2, 5, 6, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 5, 3}, {4, 6}}]]
```

> {Cycles[{{1,4,6,5,2}}]}

*verification*

```
PermutationProduct[InversePermutation[Cycles[{{1, 4, 6, 5, 2}}]], 
 Cycles[{{1, 4}, {2, 5, 6, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 4, 6, 5, 2}}]]
```

> Cycles[{{1, 2, 5, 3}, {4, 6}}]

$\color{blue}{\text{Second example}}$

```
twoP=findP[Cycles[{{1,3},{4,7,6}}],Cycles[{{1,5},{2,6,4}}]]
```

We get two $p$

> {Cycles[{{2,3,5,7,6,4}}],Cycles[{{2,7,6,4},{3,5}}]}

*verification*

```
PermutationProduct[InversePermutation[#],Cycles[{{1,3},{4,7,6}}],#]&/@twoP
```

> {Cycles[{{1,5},{2,6,4}}],Cycles[{{1,5},{2,6,4}}]}

Answer (score 4):

Another way of phrasing the question is "find $p$ such that $\alpha p = p \beta$."

Based on Arturo Magidin's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48134/why-are-two-permutations-conjugate-iff-they-have-the-same-cycle-structure), one can list the cycles of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, with cycles of same length below one another, and then $p$ will be the permutation that takes the top row to the bottom row.

My implementation:

```
findP[Cycles[alpha_], Cycles[beta_]] :=
  Block[{p1, p2, ans},
  p1 = Flatten @ Sort @ alpha;
  p2 = Flatten @ Sort @ beta;
  ans = Table[0, {Length[p1]}];
  Do[ans[[p2[[i]]]] = p1[[i]], {i, Length[p1]}];
  PermutationCycles @ ans
]
```

Verification:

```
alpha = Cycles[{{1, 4}, {2, 5, 6, 3}}];
beta = Cycles[{{1, 2, 5, 3}, {4, 6}}];
p = findP[alpha, beta];
PermutationProduct[p, alpha] == PermutationProduct[beta, p]
(* True *)
```

Or like formulated in the OP:

```
PermutationProduct[p, alpha, InversePermutation[p]] == beta
(* True *)
```

Note the order in `PermutationProduct`, which is what the docs dictate. However, I find

```
p
(* Cycles[{{1, 2, 5, 6, 4}}] *)
```

Comment: Shorter: `findP[Cycles[alpha_], Cycles[beta_]] := Block[{p1, p2}, p1 = Flatten @ Sort @ alpha; p2 = Flatten @ Sort @ beta; PermutationCycles[Permute[p1, PermutationCycles[p2]]]]`

Comment: @J.M. How about `p=Cycles[{{1,5,3},{2,7}}];
c1=Cycles[{{1,3},{4,7,6}}]
c2=PermutationReplace[c1,p]`?

Comment: I found the `findP` cannot apply to any `alpha` and `beta`?

Comment: It cannot apply to any `alpha` and `beta`, beause two conjugate permutations always have the same cyclic structure. My code does not check whether `p` exists or not, it just computes `p` assuming `alpha` and `beta` are conjugates.

Comment: Yup,the `c1` and `c2` is conjugates actually :)

Answer (score 1):

```
p = SelectFirst[GroupElements[PermutationGroup[{alpha, beta}]], 
  PermutationReplace[alpha, #] == beta &]
```

### Check

```
PermutationProduct[InversePermutation[p],alpha,p]
```

> Cycles[{{1,2,5,3},{4,6}}]