# How to add some element in a incomplete list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two list to process.Their first of each 2D part increasing monotonically and without repetition.

```
SeedRandom[1]
list1=Sort@Transpose[{RandomSample[Range@9,5],RandomSample[Range@9,5]}]
```

> {{1,9},{2,1},{3,3},{6,4},{7,7}}

and

```
SeedRandom[2]
list2=Sort@Transpose[{RandomSample[Range@9,5],RandomSample[Range@9,5]}]
```

> {{2,2},{4,1},{7,9},{8,3},{9,6}}

I want to inset some 2-dimension(such as $\{n,n\}$) list into place when the first element is incomplete.Like the two place where I have highlight it with red arrow

[image]

This is my solution for this

```
addElement[list_List] := Module[{pre},
  pre = Array[{#, #} &, Max[First /@ list]];
  Union[list, 
   Complement[pre, list, SameTest -> (Equal @@ First /@ {##} &)]]]
```

[image]

But I couldn't bear this ugly code.Can any elegant method do this?

Comment: Are the lists always sorted like this, with the first of each 2D part increasing monotonically?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Actually this is [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116587/how-the-solve-the-parameter-of-the-conjugate-permutations)'s `permutations`,I will show I how to get this test list in my later edit.

Comment: `With[{c = Complement[Range[1, #[[-1, 1]]], #[[All, 1]]]}, 
  Union[#, Transpose[{c, c}]]] &` does what I think you're after, and *much* more quickly.

Comment: @ciao Look nice than me.Could you post it as an a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per request, from the comment, this appears to do what you're after, much more quickly for large cases:

```
 With[{c = Complement[Range[1, #[[-1, 1]]], #[[All, 1]]]}, Union[#, Transpose[{c, c}]]] &
```

This appears faster yet:

```
Module[{a, b}, a = b = Range[1, #[[-1, 1]]]; 
               b[[#[[All, 1]]]] = #[[All, 2]]; Transpose[{a, b}]] &
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - good catch, fixed for purity and essence...

Comment: The last method is wonderful

Answer (score 1):

If your lists are not going to be very long, pure pattern stuff is easy to read:

```
addElems[list_List] := 
list //. {
{x___, s1 : {n1_, _}, s2 : {n2_, _}, y___} /; 
 n2 - n1 != 1 :> {x, s1, {n1, n1} + 1, s2, y}, 
{s : {n1_, _}, y___} /; n1 > 1 :> {{n1, n1} - 1, s, y}
}
```

This is going to be **very** slow if the lists get long, but I thought it was more "elegant", as you asked for.

Another easy-to-read alternative is

```
addElems2[list_List] := With[{ns = list[[All,1]]},
  ReplacePart[Table[{i, i}, {i, Last@ns}], Thread[ns -> list]]
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It seem the pattern is my Achilles'heel. :)

Comment: Misses filling leading entries.

Comment: +1 on the second, pretty efficient (first is pretty, but as you noted, `BlankNullSequence` is a killer...)

Comment: Yeah, I would never use patterns like this if the lists were long or I needed speed. Thanks :)