# How can I output list of permutation products?

Tags: combinatorics, permutation, group-theory

I have `A = Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}]`. And `c = Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}]`.
And I need to output for all $a \in A: a \cdot с \cdot a^{-1}$. How can I do this?

P.S. $a^{-1}$ is `InversePermutation[a]`.

Comment: Related my [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116587/21532).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first I'm going to use the fact that the set of permutations you have is just a [`SymmetricGroup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetricGroup.html):

```
g = SymmetricGroup[4]
PermutationCycles /@ Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}] === GroupElements[g]
(* True *)
```

Then it's a simple matter of `Map`ping over `GroupElements`:

```
Map[PermutationProduct[#, c, InversePermutation[#]] &,
  GroupElements@g]
(* {Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}], ... Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}}]} *)
```

You can also use `GroupBy` to break these up as equivalence classes, which is often what one wants to do in this situation:

```
GroupBy[GroupElements@g,
  PermutationProduct[#, c, InversePermutation[#]] &]
```

This will return an `Association` where the keys are the unique products $ a\cdot c \cdot a^{-1} $ generated, and the values are the group elements $ a $ that yield that product.

Comment: @jjc385 So I did. That'll teach me to answer Mathematica questions before I have my coffee.

Answer (score 3):

*edited to add missing definition*

Perhaps the following?:

```
A = PermutationCycles /@ Permutations[{1,2,3,4}];
Thread @ PermutationProduct[
    A,
    Cycles[{{1,2,3,4}}],
    Thread @ InversePermutation @ A
]
```

> {Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 4, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 2, 4}}], 
>    Cycles[{{1, 4, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 4, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}}], 
>    Cycles[{{1, 3, 4, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 4, 3}}], 
>    Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 4, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 2, 4}}], 
>    Cycles[{{1, 4, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 2, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}}], 
>    Cycles[{{1, 3, 4, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 4, 3}}], 
>    Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 4, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 2, 4}}], 
>    Cycles[{{1, 4, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 4, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}}]}